# Fetching data inside puppeteer site

Tags: node.js, web-crawler, puppeteer, fetch-api

I have strange problem with fetching data from external service. I have simple script to print some data from API:

```
fetch("http://sip.ztm.kielce.pl/Home/CNR_GetVehicles?r=0W&d=&nb=", {"credentials":"include","headers":{"accept":"application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01","accept-language":"pl;q=1.3592","x-requested-with":"XMLHttpRequest"},"referrer":"http://sip.ztm.kielce.pl/","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"})
.then(response => {
        return response.text();
    }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data); // this will be a string
});
```

This script is working, but only when I am at *http://sip.ztm.kielce.pl*. So I had plan to use puppeteer to evaluate this script from this site context.

So I wrote Node.JS code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.on('console', (log) => console[log._type](log._text));

    await page.goto('http://sip.ztm.kielce.pl');
    await page.waitFor(5000);

    await page.evaluate(() => {
        console.log('test');
        fetch("http://sip.ztm.kielce.pl/Home/CNR_GetVehicles?r=0W&d=&nb=", {"credentials":"include","headers":{"accept":"application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01","accept-language":"pl;q=1.3592","x-requested-with":"XMLHttpRequest"},"referrer":"http://sip.ztm.kielce.pl/","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"})
        .then(response => {
                return response.text();
            }).then(function(data) {
            console.log(data); // this will be a string
        });
    });
    await browser.close();
})();
```

But I am getting other response than in "normal" way. 
Do you have any ideas what is wrong with it?

- Due to API security this code can be invalid, also in first version. I am getting "working" fetch code from network tab in Chrome developer tools.

Comment: Please specify, what other response do you get? I'm getting `An error occurred while processing your request.` either way, in headless and in normal Chrome console too.

Comment: Check out the network tab in devtools and paste a screenshot of that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use relative url like this:

```
/Home/CNR_GetVehicles?r=0W&d=&nb=
```

instead of full path

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.on('console', (log) => console[log._type](log._text));

    await page.goto('http://sip.ztm.kielce.pl', {
        waitUntil: "networkidle2",
    })

    await page.evaluate(() => {
        console.log('test');
        fetch("/Home/CNR_GetVehicles?r=0W&d=&nb=", {"credentials":"include","headers":{"accept":"application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01","accept-language":"pl;q=1.3592","x-requested-with":"XMLHttpRequest"},"referrer":"http://sip.ztm.kielce.pl/","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"})
        .then(response => {
                return response.text();
            }).then(function(data) {
            console.log(data); // this will be a string
        });
    });
    await browser.close();
})();
```

or you can directly go to that url

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.on('console', (log) => console[log._type](log._text));

    await page.goto('http://sip.ztm.kielce.pl/Home/CNR_GetVehicles?r=0W&d=&nb=', {
        waitUntil: "networkidle2",
    });

    await page.evaluate(() => {
        const data = document.body.innerText
        console.log(data) // it will be string

    });
    await browser.close();
})();
```